# R convert list to string

Tags: r, list, type-conversion, character

I have a list where I need each individual elements as a character.

```
 > str(df_data2)
 'data.frame':  2 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ retweet_count: int  21 31
 $ quote_count  : int  NA NA
 $ reply_count  : int  NA NA
 $ hashtags     :List of 2
 ..$ : chr  "BigData" "DataScience"
 ..$ : chr  "python" "neuralnetworks"
```

The list has the same number of rows as the data set, but, I would like to have string values for each of the components.

```
 > str(df_data2)
 'data.frame':  2 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ retweet_count: int  21 31
 $ quote_count  : int  NA NA
 $ reply_count  : int  NA NA
 $ hashtags     : chr "BigData DataScience" "python neuralnetworks"
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Please post your example data using `dput()`.

Comment: @MartinGal using `unnest` would create a new row for each element of the list.

Comment: @IanCampbell Facepalming myself. Good point!

Comment: @MartinGal I feel like there should be a `tidyr::hoist` option, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: @IanCampbell Me neither. At least not in one line. My best approach was `unnest_wider` piped with `unite`. But you already gave a decent solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `sapply`:

```
df_data2$hashtags <- sapply(df_data2$hashtags, paste, collapse = " ")
```

Or alternatively you could use `purrr` and `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df_data2 %>%
  mutate(hashtags = map_chr(hashtags, paste, collapse = " "))
  retweet_count quote_count reply_count              hashtags
1            21          NA          NA   BigData DataScience
2            31          NA          NA python neuralnetworks
```

**Sample Data**

```
df_data2 <- structure(list(retweet_count = c(21, 31), quote_count = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_), reply_count = c(NA_real_, NA_real_), hashtags = list(
    c("BigData", "DataScience"), c("python", "neuralnetworks"
    ))), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```